# How To Stop This From Displaying If Nothing Entered Into Custom FIeld?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields

I can think of a way to do this with CSS, but I rather jsut do it in a much cleaner way and just not have the code appear at all if nothing is entered into the Custom Field on the backend.  Heres the code:

```
<li class="price">
   <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Price', true); ?>
</li>
```

And I tried this:

```
<?php if get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Price', true); { ?>
    <li class="price">
        <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Price', true); ?>
    </li>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: That's not proper `if()` syntax, this is: `<?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Price', true)) { ?>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a simple check on the variable to see if it is not empty:

```
<li class="price">
   <?php echo (!empty($post->ID)) ? 'Price': 'empty'; ?>
</li>
```

Of if you want to do away with the `<li>` entirely if it is empty:

```
<?php echo (!empty($post->ID)) ? '<li class="price">Price</li>': ''; ?>
```